# Accessing the imgur API with nodeJS - parameters work in AJAX, but not in nodeJS

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, https, imgur

Struggling to get nodeJS https.request or https.get to work with the imgur API (also tried with http module). Here is my code for a https.request:

```
var https = require('https')

var imgurAPIOptions = {
    hostname : 'api.imgur.com',
    path: '/3/gallery/search/time/1/?q=cat',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxx'},
    json: true,
    method: 'GET'
};

https.request(imgurAPIOptions,function(err,imgurResponse){
    if (err) {console.log('ERROR IN IMGUR API ACCESS')

} else {

    console.log('ACCESSED IMGUR API');
}

});
```

It returns the error message console.log.

Here is the (working) code for an equivalent client side request using jQuery AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
      headers: {
    "Authorization": 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search/time/1/?q=cat',
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data)
    }
  })

});
```

Has anyone here had any experience in getting the imgur API working? What am I missing?

Comment: Whats the content of `err`?

Comment: A bloody great object/array that gets cropped in the console. Give me a few minutes and I'll try and extract it.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.7.0/docs/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) the fist param in the callback from `https.request` is data, not error. Is the object in `err` the API response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [https docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback). You need to make a few changes:

The first paramater in the request callback is the reponse, rather than an error. If you want to check for errors, you can listen for the `error` event on the request.

Once the request has recieved data then you can output it.

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.imgur.com',
  path: '/3/gallery/search/time/1/?q=cat',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxx'},
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: I actually did have .end(); included, just forgot to put it on the snippet above. I'll give it a try with the your syntax, see if it works though.

Comment: Yeah that works. Think I just got thrown off by request not using the 'normal' function(err, data) callback structure and using an unfamiliar API.

Comment: No problem. There's a package called [request](https://github.com/request/request) that is quite popular and a bit nicer to use in some situation. That package follows the `function(err, data)` pattern.